# On Windows 7 Mutiple Wallpaper Scenario: How would I get the filename of the currently-displayed Wallpaper?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-customization

Given a Windows 7 Mutiple wallpaper setup. I'm talking about hundreds of wallpapers in a folder.

Wallpapers on my desktop change every 5 minutes.

Sometimes I see a wallpaper that I want to delete, because it's low quality. To get its filename, I tried right-clicking the desktop, then click "Personalize". However, it only shows you the selected Wallpaper Set, not the specific filename of the currently-displayed wallpaper.

Is there another way to get the filename of the currently-displayed Wallpaper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found an answer from the web!

The strategy is to read the value at 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Internet Explorer \ Desktop \ General

**How to Add “Desktop Background File Location” Option to Desktop Right-Click Menu in Windows 7**
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/desktop-background-file-location-right-click-menu-windows-7/

[image]

[image]